# Scalable implementation of Stochastic Gradient

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

Are there generic implementations of Stochastic Gradient Descent in Matlab that I can use for a machine learning task. I would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel (in trying to implement stochastic gradient descent by myself).

Answer (score 1):

You can find this at matlabcentral: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43647-stochastic-gradient-descent/content/stoch_grad_descent.m

Comment: https://github.com/amaas/stanford_dl_ex/blob/master/cnn/minFuncSGD.m I found this to be a far more readable implementation